# HOW TO: video will disappear after it's over and show another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I'm new here so please don't be angry if my question is not explained perfectly.

I wanna put in the header the short video and after it's over it should disappear and show the div which is under. Is it possible?

It will be a small animation around the logo of my website and in the div I wanna put just picture of the logo and navigation.

Can I do it only with HTML and CSS? Or maybe someone knows any tutorial online?

Comment: What code have you got so far? can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Aneta, What have you tried so far ?

Comment: show your video code, and how to control that???

Comment: @Aneta: did you got your answer?. checkout my answer and let us know if its working for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

Please try Following code.
Replace videoplayback.MP4 with your video

```
<html>
<body>
    <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls="">
      <source src="videoplayback.MP4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    <div id="videoEnd" style="display:none">Video end</div>

    <script>
         document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
        function myHandler(e) {
            if(!e) { e = window.event; }
            // What you want to do after the event
            document.getElementById('myVideo').style.display="none";
            document.getElementById('videoEnd').style.display="block";
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acess metadata of video, and after that you can check readyState of the video as follows.

but for this you will need to write some JavaScript code.

```
var video = document.getElementById('#video_player');

video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    if(video.readyState == video.duration){
      $(video).hide();
    }
});
```